# Multi-threading python calls to Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, multithreading, google-cloud-vision

I am running a server in a Docker container supported by a macOS machine, from which I need to send several images for processing by the Google Cloud Vision API.

It is imperative for me to be able to minimize the time spent uploading and processing the images.

I started by wrapping calls to GCV in a `Queue.Queue` and `Threading.Thread`, but this sporadically crashes my code (not trapped by a python `Exception`) thus:

```
E1121 14:15:10.902211037   25448 sync_posix.c:38]            assertion failed: pthread_mutex_destroy(mu) == 0
```

According to several github threads this is a gRPC-inspired (or httplib?) bug/feature, but I can't find steps to an easy workaround - see e.g. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11184 and https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10909

Given that this seems to be a commonly-experienced problem with no clear solution, what is the best way to mitigate it?

Is it as simple as using a single Batch call (but what about the overall speed?) to GCV? Is there no other way to safely thread the calls?

### Update:

With fear of breakage, I embarked on a rollback of gRPC to v1.2.x a la

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10909#issuecomment-302581954

Except that I had to add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my Docker container in order to pick up `libprotobuf.so.12`.

I made no changes to any other python packages.

I then did:

```
pip install grpcio==1.2.1
```

Obviously this gets expensive, but the crash rate is <1/20 calls (and counting) compared to 1/3 calls before.

**Now:** How can I test *conclusively* that this is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant part of the Dockerfile I've gone with (based on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/10909#issuecomment-302581954)

```
# gRPC fix (rollback to v1.2.x to mitigate mutex crashing bug)
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf libtool
RUN apt-get install -y libgflags-dev libgtest-dev
RUN apt-get install -y clang libc++-dev
RUN apt-get install -y sudo unzip locate
RUN mkdir -p /app/src

WORKDIR /app/src
RUN git clone --branch v1.2.x https://github.com/grpc/grpc

WORKDIR /app/src/grpc
RUN git submodule foreach git clean -xfd
RUN git submodule update --init

WORKDIR /app/src/grpc/third_party/protobuf
RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN ./configure
RUN make -j2
RUN sudo make install

WORKDIR /app/src/grpc
RUN sudo make install
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY}:/usr/local/lib
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org grpcio==1.2.1
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org google-cloud-vision
```

I will leave this open for a few days to see if anyone responds.